# Change Header Right widget for single page only on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I need to change the phone number on a single page on my website but not across the rest of the site. The phone number is in the Header Right widget.

This is the page : 
 {link removed}

Any help or guidance would be great. I'm not really comfortable in the FTP but I'm willing to do what it takes, as my developer is out of town.

Thanks,

Comment: I was at a loss so I didn't try anything. I removed the link for privacy, but @Jrod answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having to touch the theme files you could use a plugin to allow you to show/hide widgets on specific pages.

Here is an example of plugin that could help you: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/

You would want to set your current widget to be hidden on your new page and then create a new widget that will only show on your new page.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great idea! I'm so relieved to not have to do any coding.